# Underline part of hyperlink on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a compound hyperlink that contains two span elements, one of which I want to underline on hover, and the other not. A good example of this is the name / username link pair found at the top of [Twitter](http://twitter.com) tweets. I just can't figure out how they do it.

My attempt:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
<span class="main">My link</span>
<span class="caption"> and caption</span>
</a>​
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;            
}
a span.caption {
    color:gray;
    font-weight:normal;
}
a span.caption:hover {
    text-decoration:none; /* I want this to portion to not be underlined, but it still is */
}
```

​fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vgKSh/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
a:hover span{
    text-decoration:underline;            
}
a span.caption {
    color:gray;
    font-weight:normal;
}
a:hover span.caption {
    text-decoration:none;
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks Pethical and everyone else - 5 answers in 2 minutes - love the SO

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it. Put `text-decoration:underline;` in `main` class only.

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
a span.caption {
    color:gray;
    font-weight:normal;
}
a span.main:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vgKSh/9/

Answer (score 2):

Forked and fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/CtD8M/

Just have the specific span a set to text-decoration underline, rather than setting globally

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vgKSh/4/

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
a:hover span.main {
    text-decoration:underline;            
}
a span.caption {
    color:gray;
    font-weight:normal;
}
a:hover span.caption {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a:hover span {
    text-decoration:none;            
}

a:hover .main{
    text-decoration: underline;            
}
```

Just as a style thing, I never use text-decoration but use border-bottom instead with a bit of padding.

Answer (score 2):

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;            
}
a span.caption {
    color:gray;
    font-weight:normal;
}
a span.main:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```